# How to get a google page with results of query?

Tags: c#, .net, google-search

I want to download from "www.google.com" with results of query. I have this code:

```
string query = "where buy a nice dress in Londod";
string site = "www.google.com";
string page = ??; //What I must to do in order to get this page
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: Look out for the ton of questions here regarding downloading web pages.

Comment: You should *not* do this, by the way. It is against Google's TOS, and could get you blocked. They expose APIs if you wish to search programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Basic google queries can be formatted the following way:

```
http://www.google.com/#q=day+of+the+tentacle
```

(search keywords after q=)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a web crawler, if you use python, it is simple as this:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com"

request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
document = response.read()
print document
```

Comment: but it is a webcrawler what he needs. I just showed an example in python o.O

Comment: +1 cause sfelixjr is a new user to our forums and might not ever comment again if people ding him left and right for responses.